# Using ImageResizing with a custom naming convention

Tags: imageresizer

Hi I was looking in the imageresizing.net project to see if there is a plugin that handle this but I didnt find it.

I need to set up imageresizer to handle images with prefix, the prefix will define the size and different properties of the resized image.

Example is on disk we have the image
   /Images/Folder1/12345.jpg
So the request would be like 
   /Images/Folder1/small_12345.jpg

So i need to handle the request, take the prefix (small in this case) and based on an xml decide what properties apply to the original image, transforming that to
   /Images/Folder1/12345.jpg?w=100&h=75...

This bacause we already have that naming convention and we dont want to change that from our web app, but we are moving from have a batch processing of images everyday to do it on the fly with image resizer.

So the question is there a plugin for something like this or what solution do you recommend?  I was thinking on create an httpmodule wrapper that intercept this kind of image names, read the configuration from the xml based on the prefix and call the new url with the image resizer format, thing is I dont want to redirect the user.

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. (copied from flag dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic URL rewriting - you can do it with any URL rewriting module, or using ImageResizer's own URL rewriting API - the `Rewrite` event.

The [FolderResizeSyntax plugin is an example of this](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/folderresizesyntax).